# Double integral of objective function

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, integral

I want to evaluate the double integral of my objective function (named `myfunction`, see below) using the build-in-function `integral2`.

I have tried to run this script;

```
f = @(r,theta) myfunction(r,theta);
integral2(f,0,2,0,2*pi);
```

where `myfunction` is the following function:

```
function fkt=myfunction(r,theta)
x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
los(:,1)=x;
los(:,2)=y;
norm = (sum( sqrt( los(:,1).^2 + los(:,2).^2)));
fkt=norm*r;
end
```

I am making the integral in polar coordinates, that why  **fkt=norm*r**.

Matlab gives me the following error message:

```
>> untitled2
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in myfunction (line 8)
los(:,1)=x;
```

I can't figure out, what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that can be improved:

1. `los` is undefined
2. `los(:,1)` is a column while `x` is a row, so the assignment has to fail.

You can correct this by defining `los` and change your assignment. For instance:

```
los = NaN(numel(r), 2);
los(:,1) = x';
los(:,2) = y';
```

**But**, why do you need the variable `los`? Just remove it and the error will be gone:

```
function fkt=myfunction(r,theta)
x=r.*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(theta);
norm = (sum( sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2)));
fkt=norm*r;
end
```

Best,

Comment: `los` does not have to be defined. In matlab it is defined implicitely. Also x is a matrix, so your example would not work.

Comment: Thank you Ratbert. I tried the second solution, and got the following: >> untitled2
{Warning: Integrand function outputs did not match to the required tolerance when the same input values were supplied
in two separate calls with different size input matrices. Check that the function is vectorized properly. 
> In integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 247)
  In integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
  In integral2Calc (line 9)
  In integral2 (line 106)
  In untitled2 (line 5) }

Comment: When I tried the first solution (defining los), I got the following error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in myfunction (line 5)
los(:,1) = x';

Comment: @Elias for the second solution: add size(los) and size(x) - without `;` to print the sizes - just before the error line and compare the results.

Comment: @yar yes I know. I'm just giving some coding advice to a newbie.

Comment: @Elias great, the second solution solved this problem as the function executes without error. The error is after. You can now ask a new question on this error with `integral2`, and be sure to specify what the data are.

Comment: I get for x: 14 14 , for los: 196 2. I see the dimensions aren't right.

Comment: Oh! `x` is a matrix and not a vector? Why do you use `los(:,1)` then? This doesn't make sense, use the second solution. Definitely.

Comment: I see... The reason I want the x and y coordinates to be in a column matrix, is because I need to use it later on. Thanks for the advices. I'll try solve this.

Comment: If you need to transform it into vectors you can use `los(:,1)=x(:);`. The `(:)` syntax makes a single column with all the elements of `x`, columnwise. If you liked the answer, please upvote and accept it :). Best,

Comment: I have accepted it. I can't upvote, only 6 reputations.:)

Answer (score 0):

x is a matrix and you try to assign it to a column vector.

Comment: I see... I tried the following: los(:,1)=x', but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: I edited the answer. Try to use the debug functionality of matlab to look into the data.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)